# how to execute azure cli command in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

To execute ACR commands in Azure CLI, we need upgrade AZ CLI. Need to have complete steps in YML to execute the AZ commands in pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/azure-devops-cli-in-yaml?view=azure-devops

For Linux: azure-pipelines-steps-linux.yml:

steps:

## Updating to latest Azure CLI version.

- script: pip install --pre azure-cli --extra-index-url https://azurecliprod.blob.core.windows.net/edge
  displayName: 'upgrade azure cli'
- script: az --version
  displayName: 'Show Azure CLI version'
- script: az extension add -n azure-devops
  displayName: 'Install Azure DevOps Extension'
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
  azureSubscription: 'AzureServiceConnection'
  scriptType: bash
  scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
  inlineScript: |
  az account show